# Gibt es Erbwörter mit „pf“ oder „ff“?

Tags: etymology, consonant-sounds

Wenn man die Laute/Lautkombinationen ***pf*** und ***ff*** des Deutschen sprachgeschichtlich zurückverfolgt, stößt man auf folgende Lautentwicklung:

- Das indogermanische ****b*** entwickelt sich beim Übergang zum Urgermanischen zu einem ***p***. (Teil der Ersten (Germanischen) Lautverschiebung)
- Das germanische ***p*** entwickelt sich beim Übergang zum Althochdeutschen je nach Position zu ***pf*** oder ***ff***. (Teil der Zweiten (Hochdeutschen) Lautverschiebung)

Die meisten deutschen Wörter mit ***pf*** und ***ff*** gehen auf ein Wort zurück, das zu germanischer Zeit beispielsweise aus dem Lateinischen entlehnt wurde (z. B. lat. *piper*, dt. *Pfeffer*).

Der indogermanische Laut ****b*** war vergleichsweise selten, sodass auch der germanische ***p***-Laut selten auftrat. Dies zeigt sich zum Beispiel auch in der Seltenheit der [germanischen Rune, die für ***p*** stand.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peor%C3%B0)

---

**Frage:**
Meine Frage ist verwandt mit [dieser Frage hier auf Stack Exchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/are-german-words-starting-with-the-letter-p-really-of-foreign-origin), ist aber davon verschieden:

Welche Erbwörter des heutigen Neuhochdeutsch gibt es, die ein ***pf*** oder ***ff*** enthalten und direkt auf indogermanisches ****b*** zurückgehen, ohne aus einer anderen Sprache (Latein, Griechisch...) entlehnt worden zu sein?

---

<sup>Bisher habe ich nur [ein Beispiel gefunden](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tief):</sup>

<sup>nhd. ***tief*** < ahd. ***tiof*** < germ. ****deupa-*** < idg. ****dheub-***</sup>

<sup>Dabei wurde das geminierte ***ff*** am Wortende gekürzt zu ***f***.</sup>

---

Eine Möglichkeit, wie man die Beantwortung meiner Frage angehen könnte:
Hat man eine Liste aller rekonstruierten indogermanischen Wurzeln, die ein ****b*** enthalten, könnte man für jede individuell nachprüfen, ob sich ein davon abstammendes deutsches Wort mit ***pf/ff*** finden lässt. Da ****b*** recht selten sein soll, sollte sich eine endliche Liste ergeben.
<sup>Leider fehlen mir zu diesem Unterfangen die nötigen Ressourcen.</sup>

Comment: Es wird schwierig werden, nachzuweisen, dass solche Wörter wirklich nicht aus einer anderen Sprache entlehnt worden sind, wenn das Wort auch in der in der anderen Sprache vorkommt (d.h., sowohl Deutsch wie die andere Sprache das Wort aus dem Indogermanischen übernommen haben). Wenn die Lautverschiebung nicht stattgefunden hat, wird das ja gerade als Indiz für die spätere Entlehnung gewertet.

Comment: Wenn Du sagst, dass *b zu p, p zu pf oder ff wurde, dann muss das ja mal jemand an deutschen Wörtern demonstriert haben.

Comment: @Veredomon: Naja, es gibt viele Beispiele, die den Wandel germ. *p* zu ahd. *pf/ff* demonstrieren; leider stammen die, die ich finden konnte, alle aus dem Lateinischen/Griechischen oder haben eine dunkle Etymologie. Für den Wandel idg. _*b_ zu germ. *p* habe ich nur wenige Beispiele gefunden, z. B. das engl. *peg* (Stift, Pin, Zapfen...), das aber keine deutsche Entsprechung mit *pf* hat. (Der Übergang _*b_ zu *p* ist außerdem phonologisch analog zu "_*d_ wird zu _t_" und "_*g_ wird zu _k_"; er ist halt nur total selten, weil idg. _*b_ so selten war.)

Comment: @dirkt: Das kann ich nicht ganz nachvollziehen. Wenn ich mich recht entsinne, bleibt idg. _*b_ z. B. im Lateinischen ein _b_. Wenn man also ein neuhochdeutsches Wort fände, das *pf/ff* hat und mit einem lateinischen Wort verwandt ist, das _b_ hat, wäre dies ein Hinweis darauf, dass beide Wörter von idg. _*b_ abstammen würden. (Ähnlich mit griechischem Kognat, etc.) Nachweismöglichkeiten für die jeweilige Herkunft von germ. *p* müsste es also geben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sind das Kandidaten?

> abōn -> Affe
>   ablu -> Apfel: mhd apfel, ahd apful, germ. *apluz idg. *ab(e)l [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Apfel)
>   blou -> Floh (laut Wiktionary aber von *fliehen*)

Comment: @Chris: Finde ich auch!

Answer (score 6):

Hier ist eine [Liste](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/idg/idg_b.html) mit indogermanischen Worten, die mit ‘*b*’ beginnen.

Hier das gesamte [Wörterbuch](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/idgwbhin.html).

Es ist leider nicht sehr leserlich, aber besser als nichts.

Freilich eine Menge Arbeit, das Ganze aufzuarbeiten; aber hier hast du zumindest einen guten Ansatz, um alle/viele Worte zu finden, die du suchst, und damit die nötige Ressource.

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube, dass die modernen deutschen Wörter, die auf *-umpf* enden, Erbwörter sind:

- stumpf (Adjektiv)
- der Stumpf (Substantiv)
- der Strumpf (Substantiv)
- der Rumpf (Substantiv)

Beispiel ***der Stumpf:***

- mittelhochdeutsch: *stumpf, stumpfe*
- althochdeutsch: *stumph*

Das Etymologiewörterbuch von Duden vermutet, dass dieses Wort eine gemeinsame indogermanische Wurzel mit dem Wort »Stab« haben könnte (mhd »*stap*; ahd *stab*, idg *stebh*)

Das mit diesen Wörtern verwandte

> stampfen (Verb)

hat sogar in der althochdeutschen Version bereits ein *pf*:

- mhd: *stampfen*
- ahd: *stampfon*

Interessant ist auch, dass der

> Stempel

sein *pf*, das er in seiner mittelhochdeutschen Version noch hatte, verloren hat:

- mhd: stempfel
- spätahd: stemphil

Laut Duden wird vermutet, dass auch *stampfen* und *Stempel* auf das indogermanische *stebh* zurückgehen.

Bei *stampfen* wird auch auf eine Verwandtschaft mit dem griechischen *stembein* (stampfen, misshandeln, schmähen) hingewiesen, allerdings ohne darauf einzugehen, ob das griechische Wort aus der germanischen Sprachfamilie entlehnt wurde, oder ob es einen Einfluss in die entgegengesetzte Richtung gab.

Answer (score 0):

Das Wort *hüpfen* scheint deine Bedingungen zu erfüllen. Auf dem englischen [Wiktionary zum Kognat hop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hop) steht:

> From Middle English *hoppen,* from Old English *hoppian* ‎(“to hop, spring, leap, dance”), from Proto-Germanic **huppōną* ‎(“to hop”), from Proto-Indo-European **kewb-* ‎(“to bend, bow”). Cognate with Dutch *hoppen* ‎(“to hop”), German *hopfen*, *hoppen* ‎(“to hop”), Swedish *hoppa* ‎(“to hop, leap, jump”), Icelandic *hoppa* ‎(“to hop, skip”).

Auf der entsprechenden Seite von [**huppōną*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hupp%C5%8Dn%C4%85) steht dann eine lange Liste von Kognaten Germanischer Sprachen, darunter *hüpfen.*

Weitere Hinweise gibt [DWDS.de](http://dwds.de/wb/h%C3%BCpfen#et-1), wo sich unter Anderem auch der folgende Eintrag des etymologischen Wörterbuchs Pfeifers findet:

> hüpfen Vb. ‘kleine Luftsprünge machen, in kleinen Sprüngen laufen’, auch ‘springend tanzen’, mhd. *hüpfen*, mnd. nd. *hüppen*, mnl. nl. *huppen*, mhd. *hupfen*, *hopfen*, (md.) *hoppen*, nd. *huppen*, *hoppen*, aengl. *hoppian*, engl. *to hop*, anord. schwed. *hoppa* setzen teils ein germ. jan-Verb, teils (mit Intensivgemination) ein ōn-Verb voraus (s. dazu die lautlich und semantisch nahe stehenden Verben hoppeln und hopsen). Verwandt sind Hüfte, Haufen (s. d.) sowie anord. *hopa* ‘zurückweichen’ und lat. ***cubāre*** ‘liegen’. Zugrunde liegt ie. ****keub-, *kūb-,*** eine Labialerweiterung der Wurzel ie. **keu-, *keu̯ə-* ‘biegen’, auch ‘den Körper, sich in den Gelenken biegen’ und ‘Wölbung, Höhlung’. Zur gleichen Wurzel gehören Haube, Hobel, hoch, Hügel, Hocke (s. d.).

Das von mir hervorgehobene lateinische Kognat *cubāre* sowie die Rekonstruierte Wurzel **keub-, *kūb-* scheinen mir ausreichend zu belegen, dass *hüpfen* von einem indogermanischen Stammwort mit **b* abstammt.